# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item

Tags: java, android

I am without ideas of what is causing this problem,

Problem:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040028
```

R.java reports this ResID as:

```
public static final int support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item=0x7f040028;
```

Full Stacktrace

```
06-14 17:29:32.685 9541-9541/com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector, PID: 9541
        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040028
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2654)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1082)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:418)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2625)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
                                                                                          at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:418)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2625)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17555)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5291)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

The only code relating to this Spinner is:

```
//Initialise Frequency Drop Down Spinner
        spinFreqSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFreqSelector);
        ArrayList<String> FreqList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2.4/5Ghz", "2.4Ghz", "5Ghz"));
        //R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item is only a template
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, FreqList);
        spinFreqSelector.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

This error occurs when `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` finishes,

Cleaning and rebuilding does not fix this.

1. Build and compile SDK = 23
2. Minimum build sdk = 19

Solutions?

Comment: Before setting the adapter to the spinner try arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item) and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, FreqList);
```

Try `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` or `android.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

Comment: ok, so some reason, prepending android to the R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item solved my problm, however there is no resoure support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, something to note, starting R.layout gave me only present layout items, prepending android.R gave me a list of items. possibly a build error I think

Comment: `android.R` gives access to default `R.java` given by Android. `simple_spinner_item` is part of those resources. Hence `android.R`

Answer (score 1):

Use `androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item` if you are using appcompat 1.6.1 onwards.

It seems that the directory structure is changed with new update to appcompat. My older project still works with `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item`